# mysql error (#1064) stored procedure creation error

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, phpmyadmin

I'm trying to create a stored procedure but i keep getting error:

**#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'NOT DETERMINISTIC CONTAINS SQL SQL SECURITY DEFINER COMMENT '' B' at line 3**

My SQL is as follows:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE FUNCTION `prodcat_descendants` (idcat INTEGER(11) )
    RETURNS VARCHAR
    NOT DETERMINISTIC
    CONTAINS SQL
    SQL SECURITY DEFINER
    COMMENT ''
BEGIN
   RETURN (select GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT id_category SEPARATOR ',') from cms_prodcategories where id_parent=idcat and active='1');
END$$
```

I've tried to include DELIMITER but no result. I guess the problem might be in the quotes.
Can someone point me out the solution?
Thanks!

MySQL version 5.5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a varchar length on the return statement of the procedure something as

```
RETURNS VARCHAR(1024)
```

So the procedure becomes

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE FUNCTION `prodcat_descendants` (idcat INTEGER(11) )
    RETURNS VARCHAR(1024)
    NOT DETERMINISTIC
    CONTAINS SQL
    SQL SECURITY DEFINER
    COMMENT ''
BEGIN
   RETURN (select GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT id_category SEPARATOR ',') from cms_prodcategories where id_parent=idcat and active='1');
END; $$
```

Comment: Thanks. There was a problem with VARCHAR definition but a new error appears: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 9 - used phpmyadmin

Comment: Tried with SQL Manager and it worked but first i needed to set this GLOBAL:
SET GLOBAL log_bin_trust_function_creators = 1;
Thanks!